# Why isn't my anime handwriting effect working?

Tags: html, css, svg

So I started to develop my project using Inkscape. It's only for now to write: Hello

I made the path (with the "Bézier curves" icon) and the software then automatically generated the code. I saved it as an SVG and then developed the CSS.

But when I view the page, nothing is displayed on the screen.

Rem: I saw other examples on CodePen, I tried to reproduce them on my side, this time the word is displayed on the screen but the animation does not work.

Why isn't this working?

```css
body {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
.handwriting {
     width: 75%;
     transition: all 1s ease;
     transition-delay: 1s;
     
     svg {
         position: relative;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         
          .text {
              stroke-dasharray : 2900;
              stroke-dashoffset: 2900;
              animation: animate 10s linear 1 forwards;
          }
        }
   }

@keyframes animate {
   to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>  
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />  
     <title>HELLO</title>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="handwriting" >

<svg 
    width="297mm" 
    height="210mm" 
    version="1.1" 
    viewBox="0 0 297 210" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >

  <clipPath id="clipPath829">

    <path 
        d="m136.18 81.485q0.0625 1.125-0.1875 2.8125-0.21875 1.6562-0.625 3.8125-0.375 2.125-0.875 4.625-0.5 2.4688-1 5.2188-0.46875 2.7187-0.875 5.625-0.40625 2.875-0.625 5.7812-0.0312 0.21875-0.125 1.25-0.0625 1.0312-0.1875 2.5625-0.0937 1.5-0.21875 3.375-0.125 1.8438-0.21875 3.75-0.0937 1.9062-0.15625 3.75-0.0312 1.8125 0.0312 3.2188 0.0312 0.8125-0.40625 1.5625-0.40625 0.75-1.0312 1.3438-0.59375 0.625-1.25 0.96875-0.625 0.375-1.0625 0.375-0.375 0-0.84375-0.1875-0.46875-0.15625-0.90625-0.5-0.40625-0.3125-0.71875-0.8125-0.28125-0.53125-0.34375-1.1875-0.0312-0.5 0.0937-1.7188 0.125-1.25 0.34375-2.9062t0.46875-3.5312q0.28125-1.9062 0.46875-3.6875 0.21875-1.7812 0.3125-3.3125 0.0937-1.5312 0.0312-2.4688-0.0625-0.75-0.59375-1.125-0.53125-0.40625-1.2812-0.40625-1 0-2.6562 0.125-1.625 0.125-3.4062 0.28125-1.75 0.125-3.4062 0.25-1.6562 0.0937-2.7188 0.0937-0.21875 0-1.1875 0.0625-0.96875 0.0312-2.3125 0.125-1.3438 0.0937-2.8438 0.21875-1.5 0.0937-2.8438 0.21875-1.3125 0.125-2.2812 0.28125-0.9375 0.125-1.125 0.21875-0.1875 0.125-0.40625 0.78125-0.1875 0.625-0.375 1.5625-0.1875 0.90625-0.375 2.0625-0.15625 1.125-0.3125 2.25-0.125 1.0938-0.21875 2.125-0.09375 1-0.125 1.6875-0.0625 1.8438-0.125 3.6562-0.0625 1.7812-0.34375 3.1875t-0.90625 2.2812q-0.59375 0.875-1.7188 0.875-0.40625 0-1-0.4375-0.59375-0.40625-1.1562-1.0312-0.53125-0.625-0.9375-1.3125t-0.4375-1.25q-0.0625-0.59375 0.0625-1.375t0.3125-1.5938 0.375-1.5625 0.28125-1.2812q0.4375-2.0312 0.875-4.6562 0.46875-2.6562 0.90625-5.6875 0.4375-3.0625 0.875-6.4062t0.84375-6.7812q0.40625-3.4688 0.78125-6.9062t0.71875-6.6875q0.03125-0.375 0.25-0.78125 0.21875-0.4375 0.5625-0.75 0.375-0.34375 0.84375-0.5 0.5-0.1875 1.0312-0.09375 1.5 0.28125 2.2187 1 0.71875 0.6875 0.84375 1.9375 0.1875 2.1562-0.21875 4.625-0.40625 2.4375-0.96875 4.9375-0.53125 2.5-1 4.9375-0.4375 2.4375-0.34375 4.5938 0.0312 0.4375 0.4375 0.6875 0.40625 0.21875 0.96875 0.34375t1.1562 0.15625q0.59375 0.0312 1.0312 0.0312 0.65625 0 2.5-0.0625 1.875-0.0625 4.3125-0.1875 2.4688-0.15625 5.1562-0.375 2.7188-0.25 5.0625-0.5625 2.3438-0.34375 3.9688-0.78125 1.6562-0.4375 2-1 0.21875-0.34375 0.46875-1.4062 0.28125-1.0938 0.5625-2.7187 0.3125-1.625 0.59375-3.6562 0.28125-2.0625 0.5-4.3438 0.25-2.2812 0.375-4.6562 0.15625-2.4062 0.15625-4.7188 0-0.28125 0.25-0.71875 0.28125-0.4375 0.71875-0.84375 0.46875-0.40625 1.0312-0.6875 0.59375-0.3125 1.25-0.3125 0.4375 0 0.96875 0.15625 0.5625 0.125 1.0625 0.40625t0.84375 0.71875 0.375 1.0625z"
        stroke-width="1"
        style="font-feature-settings:normal;
                font-variant-caps:normal;
                font-variant-ligatures:normal;
                font-variant-numeric:normal;"
        
    />
    
    <path d="m160.83 100.42q0-0.34375-0.21875-0.65625-0.1875-0.3125-0.5-0.5625-0.28125-0.25-0.625-0.40625-0.3125-0.15625-0.53125-0.15625-1.2188 0-2.7188 1.0312-1.4688 1-2.8438 2.8125-1.3438 1.8125-2.4062 4.3438t-1.4375 5.5625q0.4375-0.28125 1.4688-1.0938t2.2188-1.8125q1.2188-1 2.375-2.0312 1.1875-1.0312 1.9062-1.7812 0.875-0.90625 1.5-1.625 0.65625-0.71875 1.0312-1.3125 0.40625-0.625 0.59375-1.1875t0.1875-1.125zm22.5 1.0312q0 0.71875-0.625 2.3125-0.625 1.5625-1.7188 3.5938-1.0938 2-2.5625 4.2188t-3.1875 4.1875q-1.75 2.125-3.9375 4.125t-4.7188 3.5625q-2.5 1.5625-5.2812 2.5t-5.7188 0.9375q-3 0-5.125-1-2.0938-1.0312-3.4375-2.6875-1.3125-1.6562-1.9375-3.75-0.59375-2.0938-0.59375-4.2812 0-1.9688 0.375-3.9688 0.375-2.0312 1.0625-3.9375 0.71875-1.9375 1.6875-3.6875t2.1562-3.25q0.75-0.96875 1.8125-2.0312 1.0938-1.0938 2.4375-2 1.375-0.90625 2.9688-1.5 1.5938-0.625 3.3438-0.625 1.25 0 2.1875 0.46875 0.96875 0.4375 1.5938 1.1875 0.65625 0.71875 0.96875 1.625 0.34375 0.90625 0.34375 1.8125 0 1.8437-0.6875 3.5625t-2.25 3.5625q-1.5625 1.8125-4.0938 3.8438-2.5 2-6.1562 4.4375-0.21875 0.15625-0.625 0.40625t-0.8125 0.5625q-0.40625 0.28125-0.71875 0.59375-0.28125 0.28125-0.28125 0.5 0 0.84375 0.28125 1.8438 0.28125 0.96875 1 1.8125 0.75 0.8125 2.0312 1.375t3.2812 0.5625q1.4062 0 2.9062-0.34375 1.5312-0.375 3.0312-1 1.5312-0.65625 3-1.5312 1.4688-0.90625 2.7812-2 1.75-1.4062 3.5312-3.25 1.7812-1.875 3.4688-4.0312t3.2188-4.5312q1.5312-2.4062 2.7812-4.875 0.34375-0.6875 0.75-0.9375 0.4375-0.25 0.71875-0.25 0.375 0 0.5625 0.5 0.1875 0.46875 0.1875 1.375z"
        stroke-width="1"
        style="font-feature-settings:normal;
                font-variant-caps:normal;
                font-variant-ligatures:normal;
                font-variant-numeric:normal;"
        
        
    />
    
    <path d="m208.33 109.11q0 0.46875-0.625 1.625-0.59375 1.1562-1.6875 2.75-1.0625 1.5625-2.5625 3.4375-1.4688 1.875-3.1875 3.7812-1.7188 1.875-3.625 3.6562-1.9062 1.75-3.8438 3.125-1.9375 1.3438-3.8438 2.1562-1.875 0.8125-3.5938 0.8125-2.3125 0-3.75-0.84375t-2.25-2.25-1.125-3.1875q-0.28125-1.8125-0.28125-3.75 0-1.1562 0.15625-3.375 0.1875-2.2188 0.53125-5.0625t0.84375-6.0938q0.53125-3.2812 1.2188-6.5 0.6875-3.2188 1.5312-6.1875t1.8438-5.2188q1.0312-2.2812 2.2188-3.625 1.1875-1.375 2.5312-1.375 0.53125 0 0.78125 0.625t0.25 2q0 0.03125-0.25 0.84375-0.25 0.78125-0.65625 2-0.375 1.1875-0.84375 2.625-0.4375 1.4375-0.84375 2.7188t-0.71875 2.2188q-0.28125 0.9375-0.34375 1.1562-1.75 5.9062-2.7188 11.656-0.9375 5.7188-0.9375 10.688 0 1.5 0.34375 2.5312t0.90625 1.6875q0.59375 0.625 1.375 0.9375 0.78125 0.28125 1.6562 0.28125 1.2188 0 2.6875-0.625t3.0312-1.6875q1.5938-1.0938 3.25-2.5312t3.25-3.0312 3.0625-3.25q1.5-1.6562 2.7812-3.1875 0.3125-0.375 0.6875-0.75 0.40625-0.375 0.8125-0.6875 0.4375-0.34375 0.8125-0.53125 0.375-0.21875 0.65625-0.21875 0.46875 0 0.46875 0.65625z"
        stroke-width="1"
        style="font-feature-settings:normal;
                font-variant-caps:normal;
                font-variant-ligatures:normal;
                font-variant-numeric:normal;"
        
    />
    
    <path d="m233.24 111.08q0 1.4688-1.7812 4.5938-0.34375 0.59375-0.96875 1.4375-0.59375 0.8125-1.3438 1.7188-0.75 0.875-1.5625 1.8125-0.8125 0.90625-1.5938 1.6875-1.1875 1.1875-2.625 2.3125-1.4062 1.125-3 2.0312-1.5625 0.90625-3.25 1.4688-1.6562 0.53125-3.2812 0.53125-2.1562 0-4.0312-0.78125t-3.2812-2.4062q-1.375-1.625-2.1875-4.0625-0.78125-2.4688-0.78125-5.8125 0-2.2812 0.21875-4.75 0.21875-2.5 0.5625-5t0.75-4.9375q0.4375-2.4687 0.875-4.75 0.28125-1.5625 0.46875-2.5625 0.21875-1 0.375-1.8438t0.28125-1.6875q0.125-0.875 0.3125-2.1562 0.125-0.875 0.21875-1.5312 0.125-0.6875 0.1875-1.125 0.125-0.75 0.40625-1.4375 0.3125-0.6875 0.75-1.2188 0.46875-0.53125 1.0625-0.84375t1.3125-0.3125q1.5 0 2.2188 1.4062-0.1875 0.96875-0.40625 1.875-0.1875 0.875-0.34375 1.875-0.78125 3.9375-1.2812 6.375t-0.71875 3.4375q-0.375 1.9688-0.8125 4.25-0.40625 2.2812-0.78125 4.6562-0.34375 2.375-0.5625 4.6875t-0.21875 4.3125q0 2.1562 0.34375 3.9375 0.34375 1.75 1.0938 3 0.78125 1.25 1.9688 1.9375 1.2188 0.6875 2.9375 0.6875 1.875 0 3.6875-0.8125 1.8125-0.84375 3.4688-2.125 1.6875-1.2812 3.1875-2.8125 1.5-1.5625 2.75-3 1-1.1875 1.75-2.0312 0.75-0.875 1.25-1.4688 0.40625-0.46875 0.90625-0.96875 0.53125-0.5 0.96875-0.5 0.5 0 0.5 0.90625z"
        stroke-width="1"
        style="font-feature-settings:normal;
                font-variant-caps:normal;
                font-variant-ligatures:normal;
                font-variant-numeric:normal;"
    
    />
    <path d="m256.87 109.14q0 1-0.0937 1.9062t-0.28125 1.75q-0.1875 0.84375-0.5 1.7188-0.3125 0.84375-0.75 1.75-0.4375 0.96875-1.5938 2.3125t-2.7812 2.7812q-1.5938 1.4375-3.5312 2.8438-1.9062 1.4062-3.875 2.5312t-3.875 1.8125q-1.875 0.6875-3.4062 0.6875-2.0938 0-3.6562-0.6875-1.5625-0.71875-2.5938-1.8438-1.0312-1.1562-1.5625-2.625-0.5-1.4688-0.5-2.9688 0-1 0.25-2.2812t0.65625-2.6562 0.96875-2.8125 1.1875-2.75 1.2812-2.4375 1.2812-1.9062q1.0938-1.375 2.625-2.6875 1.5625-1.3125 3.4062-2.3125 1.8438-1.0312 3.9375-1.6562 2.125-0.625 4.375-0.625 1.6875 0 3.3125 0.84375 1.625 0.8125 2.875 2.2187 1.2812 1.4062 2.0625 3.25t0.78125 3.8438zm-4.875 0.90625q0-3.0938-1.7812-4.8438-1.75-1.75-5.0625-1.75-1.125 0-2.2812 0.59375t-2.2188 1.4688-1.9688 1.875q-0.875 0.96875-1.4688 1.75-0.59375 0.8125-1.3125 2.2188-0.71875 1.375-1.375 2.9688-0.625 1.5625-1.0625 3.1562-0.40625 1.5625-0.40625 2.75 0 0.71875 0.28125 1.4688 0.28125 0.71875 0.78125 1.3125 0.53125 0.5625 1.25 0.9375t1.5938 0.375q0.9375 0 2.4062-0.5625 1.5-0.5625 3.1562-1.5312 1.6875-1 3.375-2.3438 1.6875-1.375 3.0312-2.9688 1.375-1.5938 2.2188-3.3438t0.84375-3.5312z"
        stroke-width="1"
        style="font-feature-settings:normal;
                font-variant-caps:normal;
                font-variant-ligatures:normal;
                font-variant-numeric:normal;"
        
    />
  </clipPath>
 
   
 
  <path 
    class="text"
    d="m167.86 131.02-0.71955 6.3046-0.82234 5.8934-1.2678 3.6663-2.1586-7.9493 6.7843 0.99366 5.0711-0.54823 4.0432-1.9188-2.3985-7.0241-0.34264 4.4543-0.78807 7.778c-1.0134 1.7567-0.20165 3.3614-0.23985 5.0368l5.6878-6.2361 3.0495-2.6726 0.0343-2.1586-2.1244 0.41117-1.9531 3.7348 0.99366 3.118 3.3236-0.10279 3.7691-3.2208 3.4264-7.7094-1.6104 5.3452-1.0622 4.934 1.2335 1.8845 2.5013-1.0622 1.9873-1.7817 1.4391-2.0216 1.4391-7.6409-1.2678 10.416 1.0622 1.7132 2.2272-0.27411 2.5013-2.2614 1.7817-2.8782 1.953-1.1992 2.5356 0.71955 0.30837 2.5013-1.9873 2.5013-3.1523 1.1307-1.1307-1.6789-0.75381-5.7564" 
    clip-path="url(#clipPath829)" 
    fill="none" 
    stroke="#00ef00" 
    stroke-width="2"
    />
 
</svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not CSS. Please update the snippet in your question to show the compiled CSS instead of whatever pre-processed language you are writing in.

Comment: If you'll unwrap the clipping path out of the clipPath element you'll be able to see that your animated path falls out of the clipping path being compleatly cut out by this. Otherwise the animation is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, the relative positions of the path you want to animate and the clip path got out of sync. To fix that, you can use Inkscape like this:

1. Open the SVG in Inkscape. Select View -> Display Mode -> Outline. You can then see your path in black and the clip path in green. You will notice they do not overlap:

[image]

2. If you now try to move and scale the path so that it fits the clip, you will find both move together. Instead, select Object -> Clip -> Release first. Then you can move the path without affecting the clip path.
3. Move and scale the path until it fits the clip path. It's best not to move the clip path at this point. Tip: If you hold `Ctrl` while scaling the path, the aspect ratio is preserved. this might prove to make things a bit easier.

[image]

4. Now open Edit -> XML editor. If you have selected the path in the grafical part of the window, it should also be selected in in the XML editor. From the list of attributes, select `d`. Copy the complete string that is shown:

[image]

(This is a screenshot from version 1.0. If you are still using an older version, this might look a bit different.)

Go to your saved HTML file and exchange the `d` attribute of your `path.text` with the copied data. That should be all, you can now close Inkscape, discarding everything.

Comment: (I checked your comment by throwing it into Google translate.) I can't really tell what was the cause things got out of sync. Normally Inkscape is pretty consistent if you transform paths that have clip-paths. In my experience it is actually more difficult to _intentionally break_ the sync than having it maintained.

Comment: Animation does not work.
When I run the .html, I just have Hello displayed .
However, I have made all the modifications under Inkscape and copied the new data from the path into the .html.
(I work in the W10 / Edge environment but I have the same problem under other browsers ) Note: I noticed with other scripts (of the same kind: "handwriting") copied from the site codepen.io that I have the same pb: the text is displayed well but the animation does not work.
Does the problem come from the html part at the beginning that I must add (with the link to the .css),
yet the .css seems correct?

Comment: For me it works: https://codepen.io/ccprog/pen/rNeWYQa Did you heed enxaneta's warning that the stylesheet is not written in CSS? It needs to be preprocessed as SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

It works !!! ;-))
In fact, I didn't know that I had to go through a compilation step (from SCSS to CSS) ???
For me it was usual CSS (besides I don't really see the difference between the two?)
Thank you again to all of you and more particularly to CCPROG for its responsiveness and its clear and detailed explanations.
Have a good day.